# Retrieving a Row From a Database Using OleDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

So, for a project I'm trying to retrieve a value from a database and store it in a place holder upon clicking the edit button.  I've tried a number of things to get this to work but it only returns the value from the first row first column.  I'm wanting it to return the value from the row I've selected to edit.  This is what I have so far in the code behind.

```
protected void grdEditPersonnel_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        //sets the value of the row selected for possible use??
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow selectedRow = grdEditPersonnel.Rows[index];

        try
        {

            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RiskManager_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [tblProjects]", connection);

            connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //sends the value of the ID to the Project ID Place Holder
                Session["ProjIDPH"] = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ID")) ? null :
                                          reader["ID"].ToString();
            }

            reader.Close();

            //Redirects user to the Add Project page
            Response.Redirect("frmProjects.aspx");
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think CommandBehavior.SingleRow does?

Comment: Your sql string does not have a where clause.

Comment: I know what it does, my problem is it isn't working as it should.  Also, as far as the WHERE clause, I've tried a number of things including using the row number, but it does not seem to work.  What should I be setting the WHERE clause to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the index value that you're gathering from the gridview (at least not that I can see anyway). You could use something like this for your command text to select the right value.

```
        "SELECT ID FROM tblProjects WHERE ID = " & GridView.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString
```

I would be doing this in the selected index changed event handler for the gridview to retrieve the value that you'll need for the edit button later. Then when the edit button is pressed, using that value to retrieve the data from the database.

Hopefully I've not missed the point entirely.

Comment: This seems to be the direction I'm wanting to go, but I'm unsure as to where the selected index changed event handler is supposed to go.  Sorry if I sound stupid, still new to this.  Also, the SelectedDataKey is not an option for me.  I'm assuming this will come up once I provide the event handler?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!  Getting the DataKey value was the solution for this!  Thanks again! :)